# asp.net DropDownList not working for in ASPNET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, class, web

DropDownList:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string sqlCoursesList = "SELECT sno,subject_lbl FROM courses WHERE sub_status = 1";

        this.course_sno.DataSource = gm.dataTable(sqlCoursesList);
        this.course_sno.DataTextField = "subject_lbl";
        this.course_sno.DataValueField = "sno";
        this.course_sno.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        gm.catchError(exc);
    }

}
```

method in my Class

```
public DataTable dataTable(string sql) {
    try {
        connect();
        dt = new DataTable();
        oda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        oda.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        catchError(exc);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            closeCon();
        }
        catch (Exception excf) {
            catchError(excf);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Code on Button pressed:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string year = this.adm_year.Text;
        string course_sno = this.course_sno.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        //this.searchTxt.Text = "Year: "+year+" Course Sno : "+course_sno;
        if (year.Equals("") || course_sno.Equals(""))
        {
            this.searchTxt.Text = gm.errorMsg("Error", "Session year and Course Must be selected in the fields", "../../images/error.png");
        }
        else
        {
            string sqlList = "SELECT sno,std_sno,opt_sno,course_sno,chosen_faculty,date_application,is_active " +
                             "FROM apply_for_course " +
                             "WHERE course_sno = '" + course_sno + "' AND " +
                             "YEAR(date_application) = '" + year + "'";
            if (gm.search(sqlList))
            {
                mdr = gm.getRecordSet(sqlList).ExecuteReader();
                if (mdr.HasRows)

                  }
........

}
```

Now, the problem is that, when i change the dropdown selection and pressing submit button it get only the first index:

```
 string course_sno = this.course_sno.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

whats i am doing wrong?

Comment: wrap your code on pageLoad event inside if(!Page.IsPostBack) {}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are binding/re-binding the drop down list on every page load, which is resetting the selected index of the drop down to the first item in the list. Only bind the drop down list the first time, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string sqlCoursesList = "SELECT sno,subject_lbl FROM courses WHERE sub_status = 1";

            this.course_sno.DataSource = gm.dataTable(sqlCoursesList);
            this.course_sno.DataTextField = "subject_lbl";
            this.course_sno.DataValueField = "sno";
            this.course_sno.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            gm.catchError(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weldone karl Anderson, yes i really forgotten about the postback :)

Comment: @AbdulRahman - yeah, done it plenty of times myself. Good luck to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Dont bind Dropdown on page load. Bind it once in code